# How to correctly escape []: in GitLab Markdown

Tags: escaping, markdown, gitlab

It tried different thing but markdown of GitLab does not allow me to write it correctly. My GitLab version: 6.8.1

What I want:

```
[Code]: [Commit message]
```

What it actually shows:

```
[Code]: /user/repo/blob/master/[Commit message]
```

What I tried:

```
    [Code\]: [Commit message]
```

`<code>\[Code\]: \[Commit message\]</code>`

```
`[Code\]: [Commit message]`
```

That does not work as expected.

**UPDATE:**

It does not work too

````
```
[Code\]: [Commit message]
```
````

Comment: This is off-topic, but you might want to consider upgrading GitLab. Version 6.8.1 [is very old](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/releases/tag/v6.8.1) (released April, 2014). There are _many_ fixes (for bugs and security) and new features since then.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is good enough, but at least the sqaure brackes are shown.

````
```
  [Code]: [Commit message]
```
````

Here an picture, of how your cases look on GitLab v7.12.2

[image]

Comment: It shows me exact the same I posted above: `[Code]: /user/repo/blob/master/[Commit message]` Which GitLab version do you use? I have `GitLab 6.8.1`

Comment: We are here on GitLab 7.12.2

Comment: I wish I could update it. I will add point to your answer, but it's not correct for me.